# Need to transform a dataframe using dataframe API instead RDD

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a a dataframe with the following data

loans,MTG,111
loans,MTG 102
loans,CRDS,103
loans,PCL,104
loans,PCL,105

I want to get result something like this

loans , MTG:111:102, PCL:104:105 , CRDS:103

I am able to achieve it using the RDD transformations

```
var data  = Seq(("loans","MTG",111),("loans","MTG" ,102),("loans","CRDS",103),("loans","PCL",104),("loans","PCL",105))


var fd1 = sc.parallelize(data)

var fd2 = fd1.map(x => ( (x(0),x(1)) , x(2) ) )

var fd3 = fd2.reduceByKey( (a,b) => a.toString + ":" + b.toString  )

var fd4 = fd3.map( x=> (x._1._1,(x._1._2 + ":"+ x._2)))

var fd5 = fd4.groupByKey()
```

I want to use the dataframe /Dataset API or may be spark SQL to achieve the same result. Could you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`.groupBy`**, **`.collect_list`** and **`concat_ws`** in built functions from dataframe api.

**`Example:`**

```
//sample dataframe
var data  = Seq(("loans","MTG",111),("loans","MTG" ,102),("loans","CRDS",103),("loans","PCL",104),("loans","PCL",105)).toDF("col1","col2","col3")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

data.show()
//+-----+----+----+
//| col1|col2|col3|
//+-----+----+----+
//|loans| MTG| 111|
//|loans| MTG| 102|
//|loans|CRDS| 103|
//|loans| PCL| 104|
//|loans| PCL| 105|
//+-----+----+----+

data.groupBy("col1","col2").
agg(concat_ws(":",collect_set("col3")).alias("col3")).
selectExpr("col1","""concat_ws(":",col2,col3) as col2""").
groupBy("col1").
agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list("col2")).alias("col2")).
show(false)

//+-----+--------------------------------+
//|col1 |col2                            |
//+-----+--------------------------------+
//|loans|MTG:102:111,CRDS:103,PCL:104:105|
//+-----+--------------------------------+

//collect
data.groupBy("col1","col2").agg(concat_ws(":",collect_set("col3")).alias("col3")).selectExpr("col1","""concat_ws(":",col2,col3) as col2""").groupBy("col1").agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list("col2")).alias("col2")).collect()
//res22: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([loans,MTG:102:111,CRDS:103,PCL:104:105])
```